# Friendly URLS indexed with %20 why?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

Google is indexing multiple links instead of indexing only one which is a 301 redirect from adding multiple hyphens.

My website url is designed the following way: url.com/id/title-goes-here/ ; If google were to index the following it would be this way..

url.com/id/title-goes-here/
url.com/id/title%20-goes-here/
url.com/id/title%20goes%20here/

so how many hyphens there are it indexes that amount of urls when it should only index 1 which is the hyphens. I have included a 301 redirect but it is still not working..

Here is my .htaccess code..

```
RewriteEngine on

# add www before hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

#if on article page, get slugs and make into friendly url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/? [L,R=302,NE]

#if page with .php is requested then remove the extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/image_resizer.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

#forces article title to redirect only once with hyphens
RewriteRule "^(article)/([^ ]*) +(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301]

#Force a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+?[^/.])[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

#allow page direction to change the slugs into friendly seo URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (?:^|/)article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /webroot/article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

#silently rewrite to webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/webroot/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

#.php ext hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Why is google still indexing multiple urls even though the hyphen has a 301 redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd search first where did Google found this strange URLs. I'm pretty sure there is no need to do this redirects.

Also consider **canonical** meta header on every page to force Google to use only one way of URL representation selected by you.

For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://url.com/id/title-goes-here/"/>
```

Regardless of fetched page, be it *url.com/id/title-goes-here/* or *url.com/id/%20title-goes-here/* search result will be *url.com/id/title-goes-here/*

Comment: That would include more code which isn't necessary to be honest, mod_rewrite is there for this reason but thank you.